# How to access nested JSON in which contains a row name which is unique to each api get result

Tags: json, api, kotlin, retrofit

My problem is, I am trying to get a single crypto currency information from CoinMarketCap API. I am using K Kotlin data class File from JSON plugin to create data classes which corresponds to api result I get. CMC api request returns the below:
Problem is, the "1" after "data" is unique to each crypto currency. I created data classes using the plugin and it created data classes corresponds to the below JSON data. it creates a data class named X1 which is for the "1" row. When I try to get bitcoin information, there are no problems. But when I search for ethereum for example, I get 0 and nulls because the row after "data" is not "1" this time. It is "2".
The SerializedName("1") created at first is not working because it tries to get a row in which 1 exists. But there are none.
How can I ignore the "data" and "1" rows and just get the rest of the json data?

The data classes created related to "1" part:

```
data class Data(
    @SerializedName("1")
    val x1: X1
)

data class X1(
    @SerializedName("circulating_supply")
    val circulatingSupply: Int,
    @SerializedName("cmc_rank")
    val cmcRank: Int,
    @SerializedName("date_added")
    val dateAdded: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    val isActive: Int,
    @SerializedName("is_fiat")
    val isFiat: Int,
    @SerializedName("last_updated")
    val lastUpdated: String,
    @SerializedName("max_supply")
    val maxSupply: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("num_market_pairs")
    val numMarketPairs: Int,
    @SerializedName("platform")
    val platform: Any,
    @SerializedName("quote")
    val quote: Quote,
    @SerializedName("self_reported_circulating_supply")
    val selfReportedCirculatingSupply: Any,
    @SerializedName("self_reported_market_cap")
    val selfReportedMarketCap: Any,
    @SerializedName("slug")
    val slug: String,
    @SerializedName("symbol")
    val symbol: String,
    @SerializedName("tags")
    val tags: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("total_supply")
    val totalSupply: Int
)
```

JSON data which I used to create data classes

```
{
"data": {
"1": {
"id": 1,
"name": "Bitcoin",
"symbol": "BTC",
"slug": "bitcoin",
"is_active": 1,
"is_fiat": 0,
"circulating_supply": 17199862,
"total_supply": 17199862,
"max_supply": 21000000,
"date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
"num_market_pairs": 331,
"cmc_rank": 1,
"last_updated": "2018-08-09T21:56:28.000Z",
"tags": [
"mineable"
],
"platform": null,
"self_reported_circulating_supply": null,
"self_reported_market_cap": null,
"quote": {
"USD": {
"price": 6602.60701122,
"volume_24h": 4314444687.5194,
"volume_change_24h": -0.152774,
"percent_change_1h": 0.988615,
"percent_change_24h": 4.37185,
"percent_change_7d": -12.1352,
"percent_change_30d": -12.1352,
"market_cap": 852164659250.2758,
"market_cap_dominance": 51,
"fully_diluted_market_cap": 952835089431.14,
"last_updated": "2018-08-09T21:56:28.000Z"
}
}
}
},
"status": {
"timestamp": "2023-02-02T16:19:58.335Z",
"error_code": 0,
"error_message": "",
"elapsed": 10,
"credit_count": 1
}
}
```

I have tried to ignore the "1" row and it didn't work. I tried to keep it as "" and this also didn't work. I tried to ignore "data" and "1" rows and just created data classes for the rest which has the information I need. It didn't work, I got nulls and 0's.
I want to learn how to adjust SerializedName section for json data which has unique rows in each request.
If that's not possible, is there a way to get only the needed parts of the json data? As I stated above, I tried to get the data after "1": { tried to get the data in here } but it didn't work.
Looking for help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
class Repository @Inject constructor(
    private val service: MyRetrofitService
) {
    suspend fun getX1(): X1? {
        val call = service.getData()
        val response = call.execute()
        if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            // Search for Integer key in json which represents coin number and ignores string keys
            val json = response.body()!!
                .getAsJsonObject("data")
                .entrySet()
                .find {
                    it.key.toIntOrNull() != null
                }?.value ?: return null

            return Gson().fromJson(json, X1::class.java)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

MyRetrofitService:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject    

interface MyService {
    @GET(YOUR_LINK)
    fun getData(): Call<JsonObject>
}
```

**Explanation:** Retrofit can't automatically get the part of the json you want, you have to do it yourself. This is an example of a repository function where you get your X1 class. I also do not recommend using the data class made by the plugin without changing it. Fields with type Any can't be parsed correctly, and plugins don't know which fields can be nullable

**Note:** This code does not check for successful requests. It only shows the way to get the data from json by converting it into a class

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, your answer got me very close to answer but it gives me the error:
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $.tags[0]
I am currently getting the map  with this code below:
            val json = response.body()!!.getAsJsonObject("data").asJsonObject
            println(json.asMap().values)

[{"id":1027,"name":"Ethereum","symbol":"ETH"............ }] but I am trying to access the values inside [ { } ]

Comment: Hello again, I solved my issue thanks to your reply. by this code below, I will access all elements I need. It will be hardcoded a little but makes the job done.
I will add the values to my model and add it to db as I needed.
        if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            response.body()!!.getAsJsonObject("data").asJsonObject.asMap().forEach{                println(it.value.asJsonObject.get("quote").asJsonObject.get("USD").asJsonObject.get("price"))
            }
        }